# How get JSON Object with Retrofit 2 and Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I am making an application in Android Studio and I want to consume API for cooking recipes, I have the following response from the API that I am consuming with Android Studio and Java:

API Response

```
  "q" : "pollo",
  "from" : 0,
  "to" : 10,
  "params" : {
    "sane" : [ ],
    "q" : [ "pollo" ],
    "app_id" : [ "02" ],
    "app_key" : [ "\n66b" ]
  },
  "more" : true,
  "count" : 1000,
  "hits" : [ {
    "recipe" : {
      "uri" : "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_d56f75c72ab67a45174441af1efe4473",
      "label" : "Pollo con Crema a las Hierbas",
      "image" : "http://cdn.kiwilimon.com/recetaimagen/23127/thumb120x90-15802.jpg",
      "source" : "KiwiLimon",
      "url" : "http://www.kiwilimon.com/receta/carnes-y-aves/pollo-con-crema-a-las-hierbas",
      "shareAs" : "http://www.edamam.com/recipe/pollo-con-crema-a-las-hierbas-d56f75c72ab67a45174441af1efe4473/pollo",
      "yield" : 42.0,
```

And continue with more 'recipe', what I want is to get only the array of hits that all the recipes have to be able to show in my application, the problem is that I get the following error:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

I understand that it is because it expects an array and it obtains a JSON object, but I do not know how to parse it, I have my Recipe model class and the RecipeService service and I manage everything in MainActivity, I have seen in some answers that I would have to do an intermediate response, but I do not understand how I could implement it in my code, then I show the classes that handle all this.

Recipe Class (Model):

```
public class Recipe {
    private String label;
    private String image;
    private String source;
    private String shareAs;
    private List<String> dietLabels;
    private List<String> healthLabels;
    private List<String> cautions;
    private List<String> ingredientLines;
    private List<String> ingredients;
    private double calories;
    private double totalWeight;
    private List<String> totalNutrients;
    private List<String> totalDaily;

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

RecipeService Class:

```
    public interface RecipeService {

    String API_ROUTE = "/search";
    String API_KEY = "&app_key=" + Credentials.API_KEY;
    String APP_ID = "&app_id=" + Credentials.APP_ID;
    //String query = "";

    @GET(API_ROUTE)
    Call< List<Recipe> > getRecipe(@Query("q") String q);

}
```

MainActivity:

```
 private void getRecipes() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl("https://test-es.edamam.com")
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build();

        RecipeService recipeService = retrofit.create(RecipeService.class);
        Call<List<Recipe>> call = recipeService.getRecipe("pollo");

        System.out.println("GET RECIPES");
        System.out.println("HEADERS: "+ call.request().headers());

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Recipe>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Recipe>> call, Response<List<Recipe>> response) {

                System.out.println("RESPONSE CODE: " + response.code());
                for(Recipe recipe : response.body()){

                    System.out.println("AÑADIENDO: " + recipe.getLabel());
                    recipes.add(recipe.getLabel());
                }
                //System.out.println(recipes.toArray().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Recipe>> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("HA OCURRIDO UN FALLO");
                System.out.println(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: If you find my answer is helpful then please up vote to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If API response is exactly what you post then the response is INVALID JSON format. You may check your JSON validity by [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/).

Secondly, your error says,

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Which means, POJO is designed for a JSON array, but from the API you are getting a JSON object.

The solution is really simple.

There are tons of plugins in Android Studio like [this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8533-json2pojo), or go [this online converter tool](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). Then hopefully you will not get the same error,